# What is wrong with predictive texting in WP8.0?

Tags: 8.0, lumia, sms, dictionary

I'm finding sending SMS with my new Lumia 1020 is a massive pain in the backside. Compared to my old Lumia 610 running WP 7.5/7.8 it's just plain terrible:

- If I type "i " it does not capitalise to "I "
- "im" automatically changes to "I'm" but "id" and "ill" do not suggest "I'd" and "I'll" as options at all, they did on my 610
- About one word in 3 it will replace a common, correctly spelled word with something else. For instance "find" is auto-corrected to "fund". I kept thinking I was mis-typing until I watched very carefully.
- "its" does not suggest or correct to "it's"

With my 610 I could type without really reading what I was writing; with the 1020 I have to scour every text otherwise it will end up as garbage. How can it be replacing valid words automatically, and not even suggesting common corrections in other situations?

It's so bad I feel like I must've done something wrong, can anyone help?

Comment: id is short for identifier, and ill is another work for sick, not i'll :)

Comment: @Joe That's true, but "I'd" and "I'll" should also be suggested as alternatives. That certainly happens on my Lumia 920 running 8.1 preview.

Comment: @Joe that's irrelevant. They maybe shouldn't autocorrect but should be listed as alternatives since they're so common - like on WP7.

Answer (score 3):

Relax there is nothing wrong with your Windows 8.0/8.1

```
Your are missing out on a few settings.
```

To capitalize your "i" go to **settings->keyboard->English**(*your preferred language*) and check-on the **correct misspelled** words on. This will let type much more smoothly.

And once you have checked on you correct misspelled words on. "ill" will be **intellisense**(auto-convert) to I'll and id would get changed into I'd.

I have first checked myself, before answering you.

Microsoft works on data for better-user-experience using it's "bing" and many other user-informers. so ..

**Microsoft says just use phone as comes to hand we will detect every thing, in few months(after working on data) we will detect even what you wanna type based on your pas inputs and person you talk to.**

Comment: Hmm, I disabled the "please spy on me" options :) But I think I have all the other settings turned on. However Do have both US and UK dictionaries installed, could this be an issue?

Answer (score 2):

From my experience (WP8 on Lumia 920), Windows Phone capitalises 'i' to 'I' *only* on English-US; it just doesn't do it for English-UK. (I have both dictionaries included.)

I can't teach it that I is a word for English-UK; word selection for training only appears to work on words of more than one letter. This is rather annoying, as the work around is to switch to American English and then have to change back if you don't want it to auto-correct "favourite" to "favorite" and so on.

However, I can get it to suggest I'll for ill and I'd for id, on both English-UK and English-US. That may mean the problem is limited to the 1020, rather than all WP8 devices.

Comment: On my Lumia 920, with WP8.1, "i" is auto-corrected to "I" using British English.

Comment: I did same on mine using Indian-English.

Comment: I found another person saying this on Google elsewhere. I am able to select the dictionary each time I type an SMS but maybe should just remove British... I only added this as it has .co.uk as a domain shortcut

Comment: Indrek, vaibhav, are you both using 8.1, or have you got i -> I with English-GB on a WP8 device?